# does grails flash scope work for multiple server instances?

Tags: grails, spring-session

We added spring-session to our grails 3 app and flash messages/errors stopped displaying.  Looking at the source it looks like it's just an in-memory Map, although I'm not sure if that gets serialized when persisting sessions:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-common/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/servlet/GrailsFlashScope.java#L45

I'm wondering if flash scope only works when running a single instance that manages sessions, or for example if in a tomcat cluster with multiple instances and no session-affinity would flash scope still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring-session currently does not allow mutating session objects for [performance reasons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/177#issuecomment-93988530). You can, however, persist it yourself using a simple filter - or use the [spring-session grails plugin](https://github.com/jeetmp3/spring-session).

I personally use the spring-session dependancy and grab the [HttpSessionSynchronizer](https://github.com/jeetmp3/spring-session/blob/master/src/main/java/org/grails/plugins/springsession/web/http/HttpSessionSynchronizer.java) filter from the plugin - used it since it's the only part needed to make flash work with spring-session.

Comment: did you do this specifically for flash scope or are you suggesting this as an alternative to using flash messages?

Comment: flash scope is in the session, this will just make the session object work as it did before. Though with the decreased performance (which in most cases will be negligible).

Comment: To be clear I still use spring-session - adding the filter just makes it behave as you expect.

Comment: I am encountering this issue. Could you share with me an example of making use of this filter, please?

Answer (score 1):

Flash scope is sever instance specific and does not work with multiple server instances without the use of session affinity.